# css3 and slide show, required explanation about the syntax

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I was trying to find slide show for some time and i am happy that I found it.
But I am looking for explanation. There are so many things that are not making any sense. Especially the syntax.
lines like this

```
 #slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-1:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul { left: 0 }
```

YOU CAN FIND IT ON JSFIDDLE THE URL IS THIS

```
  http://jsfiddle.net/6ht9c2x0/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, what’s happening here is that hidden radio buttons are used to manage the state of the slideshow. In many cases, people use JavaScript to accomplish this. Here it’s solved quite elegantly by using the DOM tree to store the current state.

You may have noticed that the radio buttons aren’t even visible. This is for a good reason as they cannot be skinned freely using CSS. That’s why they are mapped to the `label`s using the `for` attribute. That makes the radio buttons change their values when the corresponding `label`s are clicked.

Regarding the line you quoted, here’s a detailed explanation:

*(from right to left)*

1. The `left` property is set to `0`
2. This affects an `ul` element
3. This `ul` element needs to be the immediate child of the element with the ID `slideshow-inner` (`>` is the immediate child selector)
4. `#slideshow-inner` needs to appear somewhere *after* the element with the ID `button-1` (`#` selects an ID, the `~` is the general sibling combinator)
5. The status of the `#button-1` element needs to be `checked` (the colon selects a pseudo-class)
6. The `#button-1` element needs to have a `type` attribute with the value `radio` (the square brackets select the attribute, a value can be select by appending it using the `=` character)
7. The `#button-1` element needs to be an input element
8. The `#button-1` element needs to be a child of the element with the ID `#slideshow-wrap` (using a space means that it can be any child, not only the immediate children)

Comment: nice explanation thnx